# Add service reference from Visual Studuio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, service-reference

when I try to add a web service reference appear this window:
[image]

Will this be a blocking error when i call the webservice from code?

When I call a method of the webservice I get the following error:
Request canceled: Unable to create SSL / TLS secure channel.

Can this error be related to the problem in the image?
Tank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually happens when you are accessing a HTTPS site without proper SSL certificate. If you know the service and what you are doing, like when you have a local HTTPS service you can disable SSL verification, and you should be fine then.